# What is the reason for getting the default value with Intent?

Tags: java, android-intent

I'm trying to pass an int value from one activity to `Fragment`, but the value is not passed and assigned a `default` value.

The class from which to send the int value

```
int level=3;

Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleBottomSheetDialog.class);
myIntent.putExtra("level", level);
```

The Fragment that should get an int value

```
int level = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("level", 0);
```

As I understand it, there should be a completely different code, as we pass the value to the fragment. How to convey the value int  from activity to the fragment?

Comment: Did you debug your code? Are `myIntent` and `getActivity().getIntent()` the same instances? I'm no Android expert but if those aren't the same instances then that's most likely your problem - if they are the same then either your first snippet isn't called or the value is being overwritten somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send data from activity to fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)